# How do i parser html code! I want get tag in html code for iPhone

Tags: html, objective-c, iphone, tags

```
NSString *str = @"<'html><'img src= 'pic.jpg'/><'/html>";
```

Now , I want to get `pic.jpg`,

How can I search the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code depends on `libxml2` and is basically a thin wrapper that provides a more convenient interface for parsing html with Objective C. This has only been tested on iOS 3.1.3 & 3.2, if you're using OSX you're probably better off investigating using WebKit to manipulate your DOM. The following code might help you.

```
//Example to download google's source and print out the urls of all the images
NSError * error = nil;
HTMLParser * parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    return;
}

HTMLNode * bodyNode = [parser body]; //Find the body tag
NSArray * imageNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"img"]; //Get all the <img alt="" />
for (HTMLNode * imageNode in imageNodes) { //Loop through all the tags
    NSLog(@"Found image with src: %@", [imageNode getAttributeNamed:@"src"]); //Echo the src=""
}

[parser release];
```

[This libxml wrapper for Objective C](http://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser) may also be useful.

Comment: wow..

This is what I want results。

Thanks for you help, HonestSuccess.


you can help me agin?

if i hasn't libxml2 framework .

how can i do it and get the results?